# Recover password on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Я пытался сменить пароль следуя инструкциям следующей статьи по [ссылке](https://losst.pro/sbros-parolya-ubuntu) на ноутбуке ThinkPad E330, но система загрузилась как обычно, несмотря на то, что я нажал и удерживал Shift (правый).

Comment: попробуйте удерживать не `Shift`, а `Esc`

Comment: https://pingvinus.ru/note/show-grub